# Reading binary file output wrong bytes

Tags: python, binary

am trying to read a binary file, am mainly interested in the first 4 bytes, reading that in python

```
with open(target["ber"], "br") as f:
    all_content = f.read()

records = []
index = 0
content_length = len(all_content)
print(all_content[0:28])
```

outputs `b"\xbfN\x81\xe9\x80\x01T\x83\x08$\x00#c\x9547\xf8\xa4\x06\x80\x04\xa3y\xbc\xe6\x85\x04'"`

in Notepad++

[image]

I was expecting python to output the same data, specially the first 2 entries `bf4e` instead it outputs `bfN`

Comment: They are the same. Notepad++ shows all bytes in hex. Python does not. :-(

Comment: If you want to view all bytes in hex, you can just `print([hex(i) for i in all_content[0:28]])`.